# How to save a table as an image or PDF

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, kableextra

I've made a table for my data, and it turned out to be very long, I need to scroll down (in the plot window) to see all of it, so I cant crop it and its not working to save it as a picture using `ggsave`. I need the font to be big so I can't make it smaller.

This is the code:

```
phto = kable(features_table) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = "striped", font_size = 25)

phto
```

It turned out to be something like this:

[image]

How can I save the whole table in a pdf or an image to see it all without scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a *kableExtra* object, not a ggplot object, use *save_kable*:

```
library(kableExtra)

kk <- kable(mtcars) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped", font_size = 25)

#We might need to install PhantomJS:
#webshot::install_phantomjs()

save_kable(kk, "x.pdf")
```